# How to add data to a Rails ajax request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-ujs

Is it possible to use `data` with `Rails.ajax` in a Rails 5.1+ (without jQuery) app while making a `GET` request? Or `data` work only with `POST`s?

I have the following

```
Rails.ajax
      url: "/pages?title=lorem}"
      type: 'GET'
```

And I'd rather having

```
Rails.ajax
      url: 'pages'
      type: 'GET'
      data: { title: 'lorem' }
```

But when I try my params look like `{ "object Object"=>nil, "controller"=>"pages", "action"=>"index"}`

Adding `dataType: 'json'` nor `dataType: 'text'` seem to change the params passed to the controller.

Comment: I use Rails.ajax quite a bit, so I was curious to see how it handles this. In the source, it looks like it simply appends data to the end of the url. You can see the implementation [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/d84bc2b169cc0b67abe9e7efe7aa301fca570aa7/actionview/app/assets/javascripts/rails-ujs/utils/ajax.coffee#L34)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use data with a GET request; however, [Rails.ajax simply appends the data](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/d84bc2b169cc0b67abe9e7efe7aa301fca570aa7/actionview/app/assets/javascripts/rails-ujs/utils/ajax.coffee#L34) to the url.

```
if options.type is 'GET' and options.data
  if options.url.indexOf('?') < 0
    options.url += '?' + options.data
  else
    options.url += '&' + options.data
```

Other than readability, there doesn't look to be an advantage in using the data option. Your first technique of appending the data to the url yourself is doing the same thing as Rails.ajax under the hood.

```
Rails.ajax
  url: "/pages?title=lorem"
  type: 'GET'
```

However, this is similar to [how Rails.ajax handles data for POST requests](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/d84bc2b169cc0b67abe9e7efe7aa301fca570aa7/actionview/app/assets/javascripts/rails-ujs/utils/ajax.coffee#L29) as well. It doesn't perform any transformation on the data. The data is passed through untouched to the XMLHttpRequest. Data is sent like this with `options.data` passed through as-is.

```
xhr.send(options.data)
```

Comment: Readability plays a big role to me.